# Error when trying to use contains method in java

Tags: java, contains

I'm getting this error when trying to compile a class using the contains method in java. The error says that it cannot find the symbol, which I find a bit weird considering I've used the contains method several times before without any issues.

The error I'm getting looks like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/tD1ty3A.png]

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DVDAdministrasjon {

private Map personerOversikt;

public void nyPerson(String navn){
  for(int t = 0; t < personerOversikt; t++){
  if(!personerOversikt.get(t).equals(navn)){
    Person newPerson = new Person(navn);
    personerOversikt.put(navn, newPerson);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Personen er allerede registrert!");
  }
  }
}
public void kjop(Map kjoptDVD, Map eier){
  int teller = 0;
  Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Hvem har kjopt DVD-en?");
  String navn = tastatur.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Hva er tittelen paa DVD-en?");
  String filmNavn = tastatur.nextLine();
  if(personerOversikt.contains(navn)){
    kjoptDVD.put(navn, filmNavn);
    eier.put(navn, filmNavn);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Personen er ikke registrert enda!");
  }
  }
  public void laan (Map utlaantDVD, Map eier, Map laantDVD){
    Scanner tastatur = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hvem vil laane DVD-en?");
    String navn = tastatur.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hvem skal DVD-en laanes fra?");
    String navn2 = tastatur.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hva er tittelen paa DVD-en?");
    String filmNavn = tastatur.nextLine();
    if(eier.contains(filmNavn)){
      if(personerOversikt.contains(navn2)){
      laantDVD.put(navn, filmNavn);
      utlaantDVD.put(navn2, filmNavn);
    } else{
      System.out.println(navn2 + " er ikke registrert");
    }
  } else{
    System.out.println(navn2 + " eier ikke filmen");
  }
  }
}
```

Here's the referenced class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {

private String navn;
private Map kjoptDVD;
private Map utlaantDVD;
private Map laantDVD;
private Map dvdOversikt;

public Person (String navn){
 this.navn = navn;
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `containsKey` method in `Map`

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I've only ever used the contains method using arraylist and thought the method would work for both. I'll test it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is quite easy:
Map interface doesn't have a method named **contains**

you need to use either [Map.containsKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) or [Map.containsValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)) but contains as it is is not defined and is not going to work..

Additionally, Map is an interface so maybe the class you are implementing is a **HAshMap**.. so **containsKey** and **ContainsValue** are methods using internally **equals** and **hascode** just in case you have a custom class in there like PErson class or similar..

and don't use raw types with the Collection...

snippet `containsValue` in the HashMap class...

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; V v;
    if ((tab = table) != null && size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
            for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
                if ((v = e.value) == value ||
                    (value != null && value.equals(v)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using maps instead of collections. If you check `Map` javadocs, you'll see that the `Map` interface doesn't have a `contains` method. You should use [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) does not have a method `contains`. Try [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-).